# put resources in jar file and expose them to the web

Tags: java, resources

1. I got a web application, whose resources folder has a bunch of js and css files. How can I expose them to the web to be able to reference them in my web pages? And how are those files referenced?
2. I also would like to later place those resources in a separate jar file and (like in the previous question) also expose them to the web. How can I do it using maven? I mean, package them so they can be in META-INF/resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a servlet-3.0 compliant container (Tomcat 7 and beyond, for example), and place your resources inside `META-INF/resources` in your jar file, and these files will be served by the container as if they were directly under the root of the application. The jar itself must be under `WEB-INF/lib`.

Maven doesn't have much to do with your question. If you want your resources to be served by the application, and not be in a jar file, you place them in `src/main/webapp` in the standard Maven directory layout.

If you want to build a jar file containing these resources, then this jar file should be built by another Maven project, and be one of the dependencies of the Maven war project. Inside the jar project, the resources will have to be under `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`.

EDIT:

Suppose the file is named `foo.png` and is in the `images` folder under the root of the webapp, or under the `META-INF/resources/images` folder of a jar file, you reference it from inside a page of your app using a relative path or an absolute path. Suppose your app's context path is `/myFirstApp`. The address of the image will be `/myFirstApp/images/png`. Now suppse the URL of your page is `/myFirstApp/bar/index.html`, you can use

```
<img src="../images/foo.png" />
```

or

```
<img src="/myFirstApp/images/foo.png" />
```

An absolute path is much easier and safer to use, but you shouldn't hard-ce the context path of the application. So, inside a JSP, you would thus use

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/foo.png" />
```

or, using the JSTL:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/images/foo.png'/>" />
```

Comment: I already have that, but I guess I'm asking a simpler/dumber question... How can those resources be referenced from the html? And when I tried packaging the resources jar file using maven, the resources folder did did not make it into META-INF.. So in maven how is that accomplished?

Comment: See my edited answer. The original one already had the answer for the second part of your comment.

Comment: I tried the following things with no luck: -add the resources folder under myapp/src/main, -add the resources folder under myapp/META-INF, add the resources folder in the jar file in META-INF and inside src/main/resources and in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources. After that I tried hitting the url /myapp/mycss.css (this file is inside the resource folder) but still got a 404

Comment: So, you tried every location except the location mentioned in my answer: `src/main/webapp`. `src/main/webapp` represents the root of the webapp, once deployed. If you put your resources folder under `src/main/webapp`, the file foo.png of your resources folder will be accessible at `/theAppContextPath/resources/foo.png`.

Comment: you are right. Under webapp does work fine. Thx. I still haven't managed to place them in the jar file and make them available the same way.

Comment: To have them in "the" jar file, your resources folder must be in another Maven project: the project which generates this jar file. And in this other Maven project, it must be under `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`. Your webapp project doesn't create any jar: only a war.