# Access static resources of the dependent JAR from the web page

Tags: java, maven

JAR is packaged as below

sampleapp

- META-INF/resources/images
- com/sample/org/..
- sampleapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

---

It's added as a dependency lib to the web application through maven

I need to access the images from the dependent JAR in the HTML pages of the web application

Comment: Directly from HTML/javascript you can't, unless you serve them through a servlet or a rest service that maps some url to your images, fetches them and send the bytes back, in the correct format.

Comment: I tried like the solution given in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261183/put-resources-in-jar-file-and-expose-them-to-the-web) but didn't get proper idea. Could you give an example of serving thosefiles through servlet

Comment: The solution in your link looks good. Never used it thought. Can you give some more info on your project structure and the target env?